# $\mathbb{E}[B_t-B_s], \mathbb{E}[\exp(\sigma(B_t-B_s))]$ etc.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

This may be a duplicate but I cannot find the corresponding question. I have been asked to show:

$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\sigma(B_t-B_s))] = \exp\left(-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2}(s-t)\right)$

As a side note I have seen that $\mathbb{E}[B_t^{2k}] = \dfrac{(2k)!t^k}{2^k k!}$ with $\mathbb{E}[B_t^k]=0$ if k is odd, from the generator function being real.

So if this means that if $\mathbb{E}[(B_t-B_s)^{2k}] = \dfrac{(2k)!(t-s)^k}{2^k k!} $ expanding the LHS of the first equation arrives at the RHS quite easily.

I have a problem is finding how, for example, $G_{t,s} = B_t-B_s$ is a Brownian motion $~\mathscr{N}(0,t-s)$. Also, my solution really does not seem very rigorous at all and it seems that I have only managed to solve it since I have seen an expression for $\mathbb{E}[B_t^{2k}]$. In fact, the question asks to arrive at a proof from this:

$$\displaystyle P^x(B_{t_1} \in F_1, \cdots, B_{t_k} \in F_k ) = \int_{F_1\times \cdots \times F_k} p(t_1, x, x_1) \cdots p(t_k-t_{k-1}, x_{k-1}, x_k ) dx_1 \cdots dx_k $$

So what I would like, if possible, is a technique for getting to answers to questions like this. Specifically, in this question I would like to know how I can get to $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\sigma(B_t-B_s))]$ from the above. I thought I would begin with:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)d\mu_x(x)$$

I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write that $B_t - B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$  and the bilinear form as a sum of squares:

$$
E\exp (a(B_t - B_s))=
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left(a\sqrt{t-s} x - \frac{x^2}2\right)
\\=
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left(-\frac 12\left(x-a\sqrt{t-s}\right)^2\right)
\exp\left(\frac 12 a^2\left(t-s\right)\right) = \exp\left(\frac 12 a^2\left(t-s\right)\right)
$$

Comment: would you mind explaining the first line (equation) I think this will sort out my confusion. Thanks

Comment: 1. $B_t - B_s \sim N(0,t-s)\sim \sqrt{t-s} N(0,1)$

Comment: 2. $Ef(X) = \int f(x)p(x) dx$  where $p$ is the density of $X$ (if it exists)

Comment: is it more clear?

Comment: yes clearer, thanks, the stuff in the exponent though, how do I get to there? I think I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: you write $-x^2/2 + Ax = -1/2(x-A)^2 + A^2/2$.

Comment: what I mean is where do we get $a\sqrt{t-s}x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: the density of the N(0,1) is $1/\sqrt{2\pi} e^{-x^2/2}$. For the other term see point 1. previously

Comment: OK $f(X) = \exp X$ and $X \text{~} \sigma\sqrt{t-s} \mathscr{N}(0,1)$. So $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int f(x) p(x) dx = \int \exp( \sigma \sqrt{t-s} x) \cdot 1/ \sqrt{2\pi} \exp (-x^2/2) dx$ ?

Comment: exactly. {} {} {}